# SVN project cannot check out with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, subclipse, javahl

I have the newest version of eclipse ide for java (Mars 0.2) plus subclipse plugin (1.18 version of client). One check out from repository works the another one dont. When I try to add new project from svn, it stucked up on Message 'Getting remote project info', and than after 5 minutes ends with Folder - does not exists remotely. I checked access through web browser and it works. Versions below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are they the same repositories?

A couple things to keep in mind in regards to browsers:

1. If you are using any kind of repository viewer like ViewVC etc. the URL in your browser is not the same one a SVN client uses.
2. Watch out for Proxy servers.  Browsers are often auto-configured for proxies. Your SVN client will not be.  You have to configure the SVN client to use a proxy if one is required.

Other than those suggestions it is hard to provide much more of an answer based on the information that was given.

Comment: No, they are different repositories. Ok, I will check setup of proxy. Thanks